# Revisiting China with my tourist visa

Tags: visas, china

I have a 10 year re-entry visa for China.  I would like to go back again in a few months.  Do I need to do anything special or just buy a ticket, bring my passport and Visa and go?

Tom

Answer (score 1):

If you have a 10 year multiple entry visa **Entries: M(多)** you don't need to do anything but buy the ticket, grab your passport and go.

Of course the arrival card has more information like where you are staying (just mark down your first address), and you should have your return ticket information (showing departure within the limit per visit of 60 days or whatever you've been given) handy if you are asked (though I think that is rare). Also if asked your visit purpose should be compatible with a tourist visa (again, it's rare they ask, unlike, say, the US authorities).